# bash autocomplete with interactive system() call

Tags: r, bash

I'm using a shared rhel6 server to use R at the command-line. I don't have root privs. The server has R 2.15 installed. I installed R 3.1 from source in a directory I have write access to so I can use a package that is not compatible with R 2.15.

When I use the server's R installation (2.15), when I interactively use system() calls, it will do autocompletion. For example, if I have a bash script called somescript.sh in my current working directory, if I press tab after entering the following:

```
> system("somescr
```

It will autocomplete to this:

```
> system("somescript.sh
```

Likewise, if I want to 'cat' the bash script, and I press tab after entering:

```
> system("cat somescr
```

It will autocomplete to this:

```
> system("cat somescript.sh
```

Now, in my installation of R (3.1), pressing tab after entering:

```
> system("somescr
```

Will autocomplete as expected to this:

```
> system("somescript.sh
```

However, it will not autocomplete after a space like the 2nd example above. So when I press tab after entering:

```
> system("cat somescr
```

It will NOT autocomplete:

```
> system("cat somescr
```

Any idea what is controlling this behavior and how I can enable full autocompletion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)-[ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) in your programming environment, if fullfills your needs. If you have 2 files in the working directory, namely `soma.sh` and `somescript.sh`, you start with

```
system("cat som
```

then type `ALT + TAB`; emacs suggests

```
Possible completions are:
soma.sh
somescript.sh
```

and finally typing `e` followed by `ALT + TAB`, makes emacs completing to

```
system("cat somescript.sh
```